# Getting error in OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

I am using android studio and i am beginner.so please help me to resolve errors..Actually am getting error in OnClickListener. here is my code.please help me.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            goToMain2Activity();

        }
    });
}
private void goToMain2Activity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Did you registered Main2Activity in AndroidManifest?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);

Comment: You can't declare methods inside other methods, move `goToMain2Activity()` out of `onCreate()`.

Comment: Add the error message atleast

Comment: `onClickListener` needs to start with an upper case `O` - `new View.OnClickListener()`.

Comment: Am sorry. Forget to add error messageError:(20, 43) .                         error: cannot find symbol class onClickListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    final Intent i = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


}
```

or if you like a own method better do this:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            goToMain2Activity();
        }



    });

}

private void goToMain2Activity() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class));
}
```